# Add corresponding columns of data frame in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data-cleaning, data-wrangling

Here's the example data I have.

```
df1 <- tibble(a=1:4,
              b=1:4,
              c=1:4,
              d=1:4,
              e=1:4)

# A tibble: 4 x 5
      a     b     c     d     e
  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1     1     1     1     1     1
2     2     2     2     2     2
3     3     3     3     3     3
4     4     4     4     4     4
```

```
df2 <- tibble(b=1:4,
              d=1:4,
              e=1:4)

      b     d     e
  <int> <int> <int>
1     1     1     1
2     2     2     2
3     3     3     3
4     4     4     4
```

I would like to add the columns in common so that I can get a data frame like this

```
      a     b     c     d     e
  <int> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     2     1     2     2
2     2     4     2     4     4
3     3     6     3     6     6
4     4     8     4     8     8
```

Is there an easy way to do this in R with tools like `dplyr`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easier option is to subset the first dataset 'df1' based on the column names of 'df2' (assuming all the columns in 'df2' are present in 'df1'), add those and assign back to the those in 'df1'

```
df1[names(df2)] <- df1[names(df2)] + df2
```

---

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
    mutate(c_across(names(df2)) + df2)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 x 5
#      a     b     c     d     e
#  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#1     1     2     1     2     2
#2     2     4     2     4     4
#3     3     6     3     6     6
#4     4     8     4     8     8
```

Comment: Thanks! any reason why we use `c_across()` instead of `across()`? Both seem to give the same result.

Comment: @max Can you change the data for the columns of 'df2' and check

Comment: Even with different data, the two across functions give the same result.

Comment: @max I think it is due to the same dimensions.

Comment: @max Also, I am not completely sure about the acceptable behavior as some of the tidyverse function behaviors changes in each release.  I thought it is more appropriate to use `c_across` rather than `across` because `across` is similar to `lapply`